# Accumulation points and successions in metric spaces

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, $A\in M$. Show that a dot $a\in A$ es a dot of acumulation of A $\leftrightarrow$ $\exists$ a succession of dots $(a_n)$ with $a_n\in A$ such that $a_n$ tends to $a$

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of an accumulation point:

Let $M = \left({S, d}\right)$ be a metric space.

Let $A \subseteq S$ be a subsetof $S$.

Let $\alpha \in S$.

Then $\alpha$ is a '''limit point of $A$''' iff ''every''  deleted $\epsilon$-neighborhood $B_\epsilon \left({\alpha}\right) \setminus \left\{{\alpha}\right\}$ of $\alpha$ contains a point in $A$:
:$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: B_\epsilon \left({\alpha}\right) \setminus \left\{{\alpha}\right\} \cap A \ne \varnothing$
that is:
:$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: \left\{{x \in A: 0 < d \left({x, \alpha}\right) < \epsilon}\right\} \ne \varnothing$

Note that $\alpha$ does not have to be an element of $A$ to be a '''limit point'''.

(Informally speaking, $\alpha$ is a limit point of $A$ if there are points in $A$ that are different from $\alpha$ but arbitrarily close to it.)

[the definition is taken from here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Limit_Point/Metric_Space)

Translate this condition, i.e: if every deleted $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $a$ contains elements $a_n$, then $(a_n) \rightarrow a$

Comment: im so glad u understood that part, i wasn't sure about the translation to english. Thanx a lot i'm trying to understand this now.

Comment: I understood but I think in English is preferable to say points instead of dots in this context. In Spanish is the same but when translating to English I have always read points.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but looks like there was an example proof which i had to look to "copy". This means I had to use my teacher's definition.